# Error with Sqllite3 reading .sql file

Tags: python, sqlite

So I've got a .sql file that I want to build over to a .db file for sqllite3, but I'm getting a

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ENGINE": syntax error

Any ideas why? Any help is appreciated.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('newdatabase.db')
f = open('olddatabase.sql','r')
sql = f.read()
conn.executescript(sql)
conn.close()
```

OUTPUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deleteme.py", line 6, in 
    conn.executescript(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ENGINE": syntax error

---

(program exited with code: 1)

Comment: You could perhaps include the relevant SQL and the full traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divining based on `ENGINE`, you have a .sql file dumped by MySQL (`CREATE TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB` or similar), so it contains MySQL-specific extensions.

You'll have to either edit the .sql file to conform to SQLite's standards or figure out a way to convert it automatically to a more standard sequence of SQL instructions.

Comment: You are correct that the file was dumped by MySQL. How would I go about editing the .sql file to conform to SQLite's standards?

Comment: Quick googling with "mysql to sqlite" yields this tool. https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite Maybe you could use it to create a more compatible dump file. Also, it appears phpMyAdmin can export ANSI SQL compatible dump files.